# Is the latest version of Spotify linux version available on Fedora 25?

Tags: fedora, software-installation

I've googled to see if Spotify is available for Fedora 25 and it is.

What I to know is whether Fedora's version is the same as the official latest version released for Ubuntu? Is it maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currenlty, latest version in PPA provided by Spotify is [`1:1.0.44.100.ga60c0ce1-29` (2016-12-15)](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/spotify/stable/non-free/base/spotify-client).

The Spotify client I am running on my Fedora 25 (from [negativo17.org](http://negativo17.org/spotify-client/)) is

```
$ rpm -q spotify-client
spotify-client-1.0-5.fc25.x86_64
```

therefore the release does not look like the last one, but investigating the changelog:

```
$ rpm -q --changelog spotify-client | head
* Wed Dec 21 2016 Simone Caronni <negativo17@gmail.com> - 1:1.0-5
- Update to 1.0.45.186.g3b5036d6.
```

you can notice the version is even newer (`1.0.45.186.g3b5036d6`, 2016-12-21) than the one in Ubuntu.